# A phrase to say to show your respect to someone/something when they died/broken

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, vocabulary

I'm looking for phrases/ways of saying to show your respect when someone died or something broken, specifically when they did a great job. It could be used for inanimate object, for example a man can say to a car that belong to him for a long time: "You did well". I'm looking for other ways to say that.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the most appropriate thing to say, and also the most common is "Rest In Peace". Although it may not get across the idea in its entirety, the use of "rest" implies the end of work.

Other things that could be said may include the following:

- Rest easy
- Rest well

As you can see, the most appropriate things to say  in English generally focus on the end of work, and wishing that end to be pleasant, or expressing that the person/object no longer has to worry, rather than showing gratitude for the work that had been done.

The closest thing to the sentiment you are looking is indeed,  as you have said,  "You did well", however you may also opt for a more direct path:

- Thank you for all you've done.
- I will remember all you've done.
- You've done much.
- You've done more than enough.
- You don't know how much you've done for me.

Other statements that may insinuate the sentiment include:

- Everything you do will be dearly missed.
- It's okay to stop now.